# Break 4 divs in 2 row and 2 columns responsive

Tags: css, css-grid

could you pleae help me. I have 4 Divs in one row.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to move 2 of them to the next row if the width is <768px.

I have achieved this with the CSS grid

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    rid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(300px, auto));
    justify-content: center;
}

  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
         grid-template-columns: 40% 40%;
    }
 }
```

But unfortunately CSS Grid is not well supported in the IE Browser Version < Edge. 
So I have tried with `display:flex`, but cannot achieve the same result.

Here example

[image]

Can anybody help me out?

Solution was found:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.item {
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
}


@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .item {
        flex: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .item {
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your `.container` class to `display:flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap`.

So when the device screen width will be small to accommodate the `.item` boxes, they will be wrapped to another row.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Comment: picture added for better understanding

Comment: This only works when the container has a width between 160px and 239px

Comment: @Dr.Li you can add a media query for the small screen to wrap your content. Moreover, you need to add a fixed width to `.container` class based on your screen size

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex` and `order:1`

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/tmg08h34/

```css
  .container{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }
.container:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
        .container .item:nth-child(n + 3){
            order: 1;
        }
     }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>
```

**Edit to your comment work in IE**

```css
.container{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
}
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
.container .item:nth-child(2n) {
padding-right: 100%;
 }

}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: in this case you get all of the items in one column. It idea was to move 2 of 4 columns down. In other wors you will get 2x2 matrix, instead 1x4 (rows X columns)

Comment: picture added for better understanding

Comment: thank you. a good solution, but as always it doesnt work in IE< Edge :((